# Python: Centralized logging using pyzmq

Tags: python, logging, distributed, zeromq, pyzmq

I am trying to implement a centralized logging server for my distributed app using pyzmq's built-in log handlers (see [here](http://zeromq.github.io/pyzmq/logging.html)).
Although from an architectural standpoint I can understand the use of the PUB/SUB pattern, I cannot grasp the correct technical implementation of such a system.

Based on what I understand until now, since I would have N separate processes that would publish on N separate ports, I would really need N separate loggers in order to capture all the messages.

So this would mean that I need to open a separate "listener" process for every new publisher that I have on the system?

**EDIT:**
To clarify the question: in the context of the tools provided with pyzmq, how do you implement a centralized logging server?

Comment: Sorry: just realized PUSH is only compatible with PULL and vice versa, according to http://api.zeromq.org/2-1:zmq-socket; so lesingerouge's answer is better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved it using a suggestion found [here](http://blog.pythonisito.com/2012/08/distributed-systems-with-zeromq.html):

> One interesting aspect of the zmq.SUB sockets is that they can connect to multiple endpoints, so that they receive messages from all the publishers.

The solution is to use one listener that "subscribes" to all the available publishers.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, as I'm learning ZMQ myself right now. Wouldn't a PULL socket on your log service be the right choice?

Comment: What are the differences between using PUSH/PULL versus PUB/SUB in this scenario?